# Issues with Syntax in Unity and Google Play Services

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I'm making a script to work with Google Play services functions and I just got everything imported and ready to go, but for some reason Unity just doesn't like the Syntax Google is telling me to use at the end of functions `});`. I have had no luck trying to figure out a solution, and in desperation I came here to see if anyone knew about it. Any responses are greatly appreciated!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

public class Destroy : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Player;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            DestroyObject(other.gameObject);
            Jumping.Dead = true;
            if (Points.BestScore >= PlayerPrefs.GetInt("BestScore")) {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("BestScore", Points.BestScore);
            }
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
        }
    }

    public void ReportToLeaderboard() {
        Social.ReportScore(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("BestScore")), "taken out for obvious reasons", (bool success) => {
                // Score Reported
        });
    }
}
```

Here is where I am getting my source code from:
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

And Here is the Unity Error:

```
Assets/Scripts/Destroy.cs(23,68): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `,', expecting`;'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the Error because you have extra "`)`"  in  `Social.ReportScore(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("BestScore")**)**`

This should fix it

```
public void ReportToLeaderboard()
{
    Social.ReportScore(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("BestScore"), "taken out for obvious reasons", (bool success) =>
    {
        // Score Reported
    });
}
```